# how to parse javascript nest template literal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, deno

i read a file , content is "hello ${username}", i want to read it's content to template literal, how ?

```
let username = "john";
let fileContent = "hello ${username}";
let template= `${fileContent}`; 
console.log(template);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do the replacement yourself using a combination of a regular expression and a lookup map.

1. Regex: `/\$\{(\w+)\}/g`
2. Lookup-map (context object): `{ username: 'john' }`

```js
const username = "john";
const fileContent = "hello ${username}";

// We don't need this, we can just use 'fileContent' below
//const template = `${fileContent}`;

const replacer = (template, context) =>
  template.replace(/\$\{(\w+)\}/g, (match, key) => context[key]);

console.log(replacer(fileContent, { username }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `eval` is what your looking for.

The `eval()` is a function property of the global object and evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.

```js
let username = "john";
let fileContent = "hello ${username}";
let template= `${fileContent}`; 
const literal= eval("`" + template + "`");

console.log(literal);
```